# Black screen when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my PC through a USB Flash Drive. 
I get to a screen that asks if I want to try Ubuntu without installing it, another option that asks if I want to install it, download some OEM thing and if I want to check for errors in the Ubuntu files.

I try all of them and end up on the Ubuntu loading window and then the screen turns black. Nothing happens after. I have not found a fix for this at all.

Here are my PC Specs:

Model: Lenovo G505

Processor : AMD A6-5200 APU with Radeon HD Graphics 2.00 GHz

Ram : 4.00GB

Operating System : Windows 8.1 64 Bit

Please Help me I really want to install Ubuntu because I have never used it and I would like to experiment with it :D:D:D:D And also, I am a noob with technology so please put your answer as simple as possible so I can understand it :D:D::D

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the live usb and try again. it sounds like it could be a corrupted file. if the problem persists, download the iso again